# Creating files as per the column pattern

Tags: shell, awk

I want to create files as per the first column value, suppose I have ASCII data in the file, which contains..

```
400.00     1234
400.00     2134
400.05     4314
400.05     9766
401.00     9874
401.00     7982
402.50     1234
```

Now I want to write a shell or awk script which creates a file which has a name as **"Timestep_401.00"** and contains only records belonging to that column value i.e it should contains....

```
401.00    9874
401.00    7982
```

I was trying with the script as below..

```
awk '{ if($1=401.00) {print >> "Timestep_"$1; close($1)}}' awk.txt
```

But it is providing wrong output (though **Timestep_400** file is get created as a output) as it contains all the data from the file. Just the value of first column and all records from the second column of the input file.
 Content of Timestep_400 file

```
401.00     1234
401.00     2134
401.00     4314
401.00     9766
401.00     9874
401.00     7982
401.00     1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the main thing wrong with your script is a typo: `=` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Personally I'd use a string comparison, to avoid having to think about issues related to floating point values (and because awk sees the fields as strings anyway).

I'd also lose the unnecessary `if` because awk scripts work like `condition { action }`.

```
awk '$1 == "401.00" { print > ("Timestamp_"$1) }' awk.txt
```

I'm guessing that you want to use `>` instead of `>>`. `>` means "open and truncate the file" but on subsequent lines, the file is already open, so it will be appended to. If `Timestamp_401.00` already exists before you run the script and you to preserve its contents, use `>>` as you were doing.

I guess you meant to `close` the file that you had just written to but it's not necessary to do this once per line - in fact, this would mean that `>` reopened (and truncated) the file every time the block is executed.